# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, locale, actionview

Im new in rails, I tried to do this in application.html.rb:

```
 <%= select_tag 'set_locale',
    options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s), :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
        <%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
        <%= javascript_tag "$$('.locale input').each(Element.hide)" %>
```

and I have the file i18n.rb in config/initializers directory, the code of this file is:

```
#encoding: utf-8
I18n.default_locale = :en

LANGUAGES = [
  ["English",                  "en"],
  ["Espa&ntilde;ol".html_safe, "es"]]
```

But when I run I receive this error message:

`uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::LANGUAGES`

I think the problem is with `LANGUAGE` because rails dont know it, but I dont know want can i do.

Im using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.5.

Please, I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `::LANGUAGES` in view?

But I think better practice is to specify language select helper method in application helper.

In helper:

```
def languages_select_tag(name = 'set_locale')
  languages = [["English","en"],["Espa&ntilde;ol".html_safe, "es"]]
  options = options_for_select(languages, I18n.locale.to_s)
  select_tag(name, option, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()')
end
```

In view:

```
<%= languages_select_tag %>
<%= submit_tag 'submit' %>
<%= javascript_tag "$$('.locale input').each(Element.hide)" %>
```

Comment: Hi My friend Retro, thank you so much for your help, your code work fine, I understand that the constant must be in class and module's but I took that code from the book: Agile Web Development with Rails 4 edition I don't think thats be an error from the author, what do you think? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I kind of fixed it by adding

```
def languages
  LANGUANGES
end
```

in the i18n.rb file.
Then using it

```
options_for_select(languages, I18n.locale.to_s)
```